# Can I annotate a numpy array when saving it with savez

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose my program creates a large array of data which I then save with numpy's savez routine. However, I'd also like to store some additional information together with that array. Examples would be the git commit id of the current version, and the input parameters used to generate the data so that later I can look at the data and know exactly how I created it.

Is there a way to save this information directly together with the array in a npz file, or would I have to create a separate file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to:

```
In [2]: a = np.arange(10)

In [3]: b = 'git push'

In [5]: np.savez('file',a=a,b=b)

In [7]: data = np.load('file.npz')

In [8]: data.keys()
Out[8]: ['a', 'b']

In [9]: data['a']
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [10]: str(data['b'])
Out[10]: 'git push'
```

So you can save arbitrary named data and get a dictionary-like object out. Perhaps a better format to use that may be more flexible and has built in support for all sorts of metadata is hdf5 using either h5py or pytables:

http://h5py.alfven.org/docs/

http://www.pytables.org/

Comment: Ah, you added the hdf suggestion just as I was finishing up my answer! I'll leave mine too, just as it has an example of using `h5py`.  Nice answer, though.

Comment: I found both your and Joe Kington's answer very helpful. I couldn't decide which one to accept so I took yours because you were first :)

Answer (score 7):

In a nutshell, you can (`.npz` is just a pickled dict) but you're probably better off switching to something else.  (It looks like @JoshAdel just posted a nice example of doing this if you do want to stick with `.npz`.)

HDF is a far better choice for something like this.

Each group or dataset in an hdf file can store attributes.

I'd reccommend `h5py` for storing numpy arrays in an hdf file.

As an example:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

somearray = np.random.random(100)

f = h5py.File('test.hdf', 'w')

dataset = f.create_dataset('my_data', data=somearray)

# Store attributes about your dataset using dictionary-like access
dataset.attrs['git id'] = 'yay this is a string'

f.close()
```

Comment: +1 I use h5py a lot in my research. I have much less experience with pytables, although I know a lot of people who use it.

Comment: This is very helpful JoshAdel. Are there any limits on the size of these attributes?